# emulator connection to wampserver

Tags: android, mysql

I' m developing a login interface (android). I used to connect my emulator to the database MySQL. But it doesn't work.it always display that the user not found even that I inserted it. this is picture of my emulator:

[image]

build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mouna.androidproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

}

AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java:

```
package com.example.mouna.androidproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
Button b;
EditText et,pass;
TextView tv;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, "",
                    "Validating user...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    login();
                              }
            }).start();
        }
    });

  }

  void login(){
    try{

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new       HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php");  
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            startActivity(new Intent(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, UserPage.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

userpage.java:
    package com.example.mouna.androidproject;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UserPage extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.userpage);

}
}
```

php file:

```
 mysqli_select_db($localhost,$database_localhost);
 if (isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['password'])) {
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $query_search = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."'   AND   password = '".$password. "'";
 $query_exec = mysqli_query($localhost,$query_search) or    die(mysqli_error());
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec)){
  $output[]=$row;}
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysqli_close();

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: From that image of your emulator, I see straight HTML in your response. Maybe your problem is the PHP code. In other words, `response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found") == false`

Comment: Yea, I know. Your PHP most likely has an error. Just look at your response. Obviously it does not equal `"User Found"`